# How to Get only Duplicate data from one table?

Tags: sql

I have one table and many data like duplicate values and single values.
But I want to get only duplicate value data's , not single value.

Answer (score 7):

```
SELECT columnWithDuplicates, count(*) FROM myTable
GROUP BY columnWithDuplicates HAVING (count(*) > 1);
```

Answer (score 0):

The above query will show the duplicated values. And once you provide that to a business user, their next question will be what happened? How did these get there? Is there a pattern to the duplicates?  What's often more informative is to see the whole rows containing those values to help determine *why* there are duplicates.

```
-- this query finds all the values in T that
-- exist in the derived table D where D is the list of
-- all the values in columnWithDuplicates that occur more than once
SELECT DISTINCT
    T.* 
FROM
    myTable T 
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        -- this identifies the duplicated values
        -- courtesy of Brian Roach
        SELECT 
            columnWithDuplicates
        ,   count(*) AS rowCount
        FROM 
            myTable 
        GROUP BY 
            columnWithDuplicates 
        HAVING 
            (count(*) > 1)
    ) D 
        ON D.columnWithDuplicates = T.columnWithDuplicates
```